# AS3 images Load from xml

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this code to load my data from xml.
I want to use this data to play some sounds and load 3 images.

```
function loadthexml():void {

    var numRecs:int = xmlContent.paths.length();
    var t_name: String;
    var t_sound: String;
    var t_age: String;
    var t_place: String;
    var t_everyday: String;
    var t_youwill: String;
    var t_pic1: String;
    var t_pic2: String;
    var t_pic3: String;
    var i:int;

    for (i=0; i<numRecs; i++) {

    t_name=String(xmlContent.paths[i].thename); 
    txtOutput2.text = t_name;

    t_sound=String(xmlContent.paths[i].soundpath);  
    txtOutput3.text = t_sound;

    t_age=String(xmlContent.paths[i].theage);   
    txtOutput4.text = t_age;

    t_place=String(xmlContent.paths[i].theplace);   
    txtOutput5.text = t_place;

    t_everyday=String(xmlContent.paths[i].everyday);    
    txtOutput6.text = t_everyday;

    t_youwill=String(xmlContent.paths[i].youwill);  
    txtOutput7.text = t_youwill;

    t_pic1=String(xmlContent.paths[i].t_pic1);  
    t_pic2=String(xmlContent.paths[i].t_pic2);  
    t_pic3=String(xmlContent.paths[i].t_pic3);

    pic1holder.addChild(t_pic1);
pic2holder.addChild(t_pic2);
pic3holder.addChild(t_pic3);



    }
```

So i have 3 movie clips with instance names pic1holder - picholder - pic3holder but with
my code i cannot load the three pictures.

Where am i wrong?

Regards!

Comment: Looks like your confusing text (the value of t_pic1/2/3) with a display object.   What is a sample value of `xmlContent.paths[i].t_pic1`? is it a path to an image? binary data?

Comment: Check out this answer. Its very well written.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990010/load-images-into-separate-movie-clips-from-a-xml-flash-actionscript-3-0

Comment: Showing your XML data would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i solved it:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(t_pic1);
myLoader.load(fileRequest);
pic1holder.addChild(myLoader);

var myLoader2:Loader = new Loader();
var fileRequest2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(t_pic2);
myLoader2.load(fileRequest2);
pic2holder.addChild(myLoader2);

var myLoader3:Loader = new Loader();
var fileRequest3:URLRequest = new URLRequest(t_pic3);
myLoader3.load(fileRequest3);
pic3holder.addChild(myLoader3);
```

Thank you all for your response!